# Sending smtp emails with SpringBoot application

Tags: linux, spring-boot, smtp, ubuntu-16.04, postfix-mta

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I've configured the springboot properties as follows:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=nunet@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=nunet999!
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port = 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
spring.mail.propertirs.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
```

and It is working fine when sending emails. I also have an email address from my domain info@nunet.com

I am using Postfix to forward the Emails from info@nunet.com to  to nunet@gmail.com and its working fine.

I would like to know if there is a way to do it on the other way around. Send emails from info@nunet.com but using nunet@gmail.com smtp to avoid to install a Mail server.

or basically I would like to know how to extract the smtp properties from my linux server, because from there I can send emails using the command

```
cat ~/test_message | mail -s 'Test email subject line' nunet@gmail.com
```

Comment: Did I undestand it right, that you want to send emails threw the gmail smtp server and use a nunet.com sender address?

Comment: yes, maybe it is not possible, right ?

Comment: Are you looking for google suite ( https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_in/ )??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Google Suite's [email feature](https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en_in/products/gmail/). With this feature You can create a custom email address using your own domain name then send & receive emails with Gmail ([Gmail Suite](https://support.google.com/a/topic/1611273)).

After configuration working with Gmail's SMTP is same as you done before.

Read more: https://digital.com/blog/create-email-using-gmail/#ixzz5Sxusynvb

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't need any extra work on your code, Google handle this process. It's like you send email from your Gmail account, but email address is from your domain.

Comment: @EnNuNYetdeCanCalÇadA what is your host control panel? This is google help for setting up MX records in various Control-panels. https://support.google.com/a/topic/1611273

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is possible with SMTP, but the most SMTP-Hoster don't allow it to avoid spammers to send spam. Furthermore the most E-Mail-Hoster will detected that kind of mails as spam.